# VBA: Find duplicates in column a, add sums of b and c

Tags: excel, vba

Pretty new to all this and just giving it all a go. Just building a pet project in excel and it's coming along nicely(i'm actually midly in love with it and enjoying myself far to much!)...until i hit this wall and i'm totally stumped.

Anyway, I've hit a wall and have been search for ages to get an answer.

I'm trying to configure a vba to find duplicaates in column a(so say items). When it finds a duplicate i want it to take column b and add the sum and take column c and add the sums. All duplicates get deleted and it gets replaced/new sheet with it nice and neat. I'm tried like 100 different things, search and search and got nowhere.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

[image]

I'm looking at something like but it only works on summing the b column.

```
Dim Cl As Range
Dim Cnt As Long

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each Cl In Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(Cl.Value) Then
            .Add Cl.Value, Cl.Offset(, 1).Value
        Else
            .Item(Cl.Value) = .Item(Cl.Value) + Cl.Offset(, 1).Value
            
        End If
    Next Cl
    Sheets("test").Range("A1").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
    Sheets("test").Range("B1").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.items)
    End With
```

But it only works for the first column. I can't work out how to do it with the second range. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some sample data rather than an image? Also, how is it not working for the second column? How should it work for the second column? P.S. Why aren't you adding the value from column C in the code?

Comment: @norie: It looks that each column values must be added separately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub DuplicatesSum2Columns()
 Dim cl As Range, arr, arrFin, El, k As Long
 
 With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each cl In Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
        If Not .Exists(cl.value) Then
            .Add cl.value, cl.Offset(, 1).value & "|" & cl.Offset(, 2).value
        Else
            arr = Split(.item(cl.value), "|") 'split the dictionary item to load the two columns
            .item(cl.value) = arr(0) + cl.Offset(, 1).value & "|" & arr(1) + cl.Offset(, 2).value            
        End If
    Next cl
    ReDim arrFin(1 To .count, 1 To 3): k = 1
    'Put the dictionary keys and split items in the final array:
    For Each El In .Keys
        arrFin(k, 1) = El
        arrFin(k, 2) = CLng(Split(.item(El), "|")(0))
        arrFin(k, 3) = CLng(Split(.item(El), "|")(1))
        k = k + 1
    Next
    'drop the array values at once:
    Sheets("test").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a dream! Just added a clear sheetbefore the redim and now it's function exactly how i want it. Thank you every so much!

Comment: @saraj999: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without VBA in O365.

```
E1 =UNIQUE(A1:A16)
F1 =SUMIFS(B$1:B$16,$A$1:$A$16,$E1#)
G1 =SUMIFS(B$1:B$16,$A$1:$A$16,$E1#)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly misread the question, thought you wanted to sum both columns together nor separately.

```
Sub SumDups()
Dim dic As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim arrDataIn() As Variant
Dim arrDataOut() As Variant
Dim arrSums() As Variant
Dim idxRow As Long
Dim ky As Variant

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    arrDataIn = rng.Value

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For idxRow = LBound(arrDataIn, 1) To UBound(arrDataIn, 1)
        ky = arrDataIn(idxRow, 1)

        If dic.Exists(ky) Then
            arrSums = dic(ky)
        Else
            arrSums = Array(0, 0)
        End If

        arrSums = Array(arrSums(0) + arrDataIn(idxRow, 2), arrSums(1) + arrDataIn(idxRow, 3))

        dic(ky) = arrSums

    Next idxRow

    ReDim arrDataOut(1 To dic.Count, 1 To 3)

    idxRow = 1

    For Each ky In dic.Keys
        arrSums = dic(ky)
        arrDataOut(idxRow, 1) = ky
        arrDataOut(idxRow, 2) = arrSums(0)
        arrDataOut(idxRow, 3) = arrSums(1)
        idxRow = idxRow + 1
    Next ky

    Range("E1").Resize(dic.Count, 3).Value = arrDataOut

End Sub
```